# How do i update mysql views when a column is added/deleted from the table?

Tags: php, mysql, tableview

I created a table and then some views for the table. Now i altered the table to add another column in it.But the views are not updated.It doesn't have the column that is added in the table.Is there any way to modify view structure automatically?

Comment: Short answer: No. Long answer: Maybe? You didn't show your schema or your view code. This is important.

Comment: view is like virtual column so when you have already created ...its just drop them and create new view using your updated table query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `alter view` command to modify the view and change the columns.

For example, if your view is view1 and table is table1, you can do something like this:

```
ALTER
VIEW view1 col1, col2,  col3, new_col
AS select tcol1, tcol2, tcol3, new_tcol from table1
```

[Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-view.html) is the documentation for the full syntax for mysql.

Answer (score 0):

You can have one text/sql file with the definition of all your views and run it everytime you update your tables. So, you don't need to update every view.

Something like that:

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS view1;
CREATE VIEW view1 AS
    SELECT * FROM table1;

DROP VIEW IF EXISTS view2;
CREATE VIEW view2 AS
    SELECT * FROM table2;
```